# JUnit Test Case need to test a directory

Tags: java, junit, directory

I'm having difficult time figuring out how to test a directory that I've made myself and imported in the Project Files.

Currently I have:

```
File file = new File(ExplorerView.class.getResource("/ExplorerViewTestFolder"));
```

Which I'm trying grab from here to test[image: Picture]

```
ExplorerView explorer = new ExplorerView();

explorer.countFilesAndFolders("/ExplorerViewTestFolder");
```

Edit2: Changed to

```
public class ExplorerViewTests {

@Test
public void testCountFilesAndFolders() {

    ExplorerView explorer = new ExplorerView();

    explorer.countFilesAndFolders("/ExplorerViewTestFolder");


}
```

Error: [image]

EDIT3: [image]

EDIT4:

```
public int countFilesAndFolders(File f) {
    if (f.isFile()) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        int total = 0;

        for (File file : f.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isHidden() == false) {
                total += countFilesAndFolders(file);
            }
        }
        return total + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with `test a directory`? Do you have any example code?

Comment: And what happens when you attempt to run your existing program (from yesterday, right?)?

Comment: @jiaweizhang everything runs fine as far as I can tell! I just need to make some test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple JUnit test looks something like this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MyTests {

    @Test
    public void directoryTest() {

        // ExplorerView class is tested
        ExplorerView explorer = new ExplorerView();

        explorer.countFilesAndFolders("ExplorerViewTestFolder");

        // assert statements
        assertEquals("filecount must be same ", 12, explorer.getNumberFiles());
        assertEquals("directorycount must be same ", 2, explorer.getNumberDirectories());
    }

}
```

If the `assertEquals` evaluates to true - if `explorer.getNumberFiles() == 12` and `explorer.getNumberDirectories() == 2`, then the JUnit tests will pass. Otherwise, they will fail.

Comment: I'm getting an error with that. I've went and added it to the main post. (Sorry if I'm doing this stackoverflow thing wrong).

Comment: Ah. Easy fix. It's expecting a `File` but you're giving it a `String`. So just do what we did yesterday with `File f = new File("/ExplorerViewTestFolder")`. So that line should be: `explorer.countFilesAndFolders(new File("/ExplorerViewTestFolder"));`

Comment: I've tried that, unless I'm reading you wrong haha. Here, I did an update number 3 and it's giving me something else.

Comment: Ah. `static` - click the second option to make the method non-static (within the IDE). Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903537/i-want-to-know-the-difference-between-static-method-and-non-static-method) to learn more about static vs non-static

Comment: Ah gotcha, I see now. And I guess that's working fine now, but I'm getting a NullPointerException with my code now I guess.

Comment: Can you go ahead and post your complete `Explorer` code? The `NullPointerException` seems to be occurring somewhere within `explorer`, such as when `null` is returned because no files are present in a directory (yesterday's code)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95636/discussion-between-jiaweizhang-and-projectdefy).