# Why instantiate main class when you can use static?

Tags: java

My friend is new to programming. He said he had a problem in his code and shared his screen on Skype. I saw he had instantiated his Main class to use all the functions, etc. It looked like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.Example();
}
```

I've also noticed this in a couple tutorials online. The thing is, since you shouldn't really have more than one main, why instantiate it?

Answer (score 3):

You could argue that it's better that way.

You should probably not have a `Main` class to begin with but one with a proper object oriented purpose that encapsulates something.

The `main` method has to be unfortunately inside one of your classes.
But that doesn't mean that the poor class that has to house the `main` method isn't allowed to be instantiated.

In pure OOP there is no place for `static` at all. Not even utility classes: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/05/oop-alternative-to-utility-classes.html

Comment: It is sorta obsolete. I'm working on a dinky little program now and Main is just sitting there invoking outside methods and wasting space :\

Answer (score 1):

This code initialize the `Main` class. Not `public static void main()` method !!!

It is a common thing in Java as per my knowledge as you can't always use `static` classes or methods.

you cannot access `non-static` variables or methods inside `static` methods (like `main` method). Hence the way to do is to create an instance of the class itself and use `non-static` variables or methods.

Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

Answer (score 1):

The difference between using static and non-static context can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903537/i-want-to-know-the-difference-between-static-method-and-non-static-method)

Assuming your asking why he would create a object of his main class the answer would be to access non-static methods from within static context. Without that main class object, he would only be able to access static methods and classes. I would recommend looking into Object Oriented Programming basics, which can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/).

```
 Main main = new Main(); //creates object of class Main
 main.Example(); //calls method Example from object main
```

What your friend did was create a instance of the class and store it into memory. He is not instantiating the main method, but the class Main. This gives him the ability to alter information belonging to his main object of the class Main.

The purpose for doing this is to access non-static methods in the class Main.

Comment: I understand the difference between static and non-static. Just I don't like the idea of having to instantiate something if I'm only using it once.

Comment: The reason for adding those two lines is so you can access non-static methods

Comment: @Hutch it isn't necessarily being used once. Probably, the `main.Example()` call is going to do a bunch of other stuff. That other stuff may include accessing other instance variables or instance methods of the Main object.

Comment: @Hutch also this is just a example situation. most programs will call many more methods then just one.

Comment: I know this. But this is the Main class, so I don't see much reason why to use non-static. There is only going to be one static main class, so might as well make everything static and just refer to "Main.example" outside of classes.

It honestly just doesn't feel right making an instance of Main.

Comment: @DougRichardson IIRC he was just creating a JFrame and making labels, etc. I'm pretty sure he was asking about ripping the function he had and putting that into a separate class on it's own.

Comment: you don't want to do everything in static

Comment: @Ryan I was assuming it was convention, but wanted to ask if there was something I was missing on.

Honestly, it just feels weird doing.

Answer (score 1):

The static methods can be easily accessed with the following format.
ClassName.methodname().
But instance method of the class can not be called without creating. If we have all the methods static, in that case there is no need of the the creation of the objects as we do it in utility classes.

Comment: Exactly. I want to be able to access Main wherever and not have to create a new instance just for a simple property. People linked me to other people's questions in which the classes are totally ok to be instantiated. However, I feel the Main is an exception.