# How can I implement a linked list in java?

Tags: linked-list

I implement a linked list from scratch in java according to the book of EPI. However this is an error when creating list nodes.

My code is

```
public class Example {

    class ListNode<T> {
        public T data;
        public ListNode<T> next;

        ListNode(T data, ListNode<T> next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world.");
        ListNode<Integer> p1  = new ListNode<Integer>(123, null);
    }

}
```

This error is

```
Example.java:19: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
        p1 = new ListNode<Integer>(123, null);
             ^
1 error
```

---

It works when I revise it a little bit.

```
public static class ListNode<T> {
    public T data;
    public ListNode<T> next;

    ListNode(T data, ListNode<T> next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

But why I should add static?

Comment: Because you want a static linked list, rather than a nested linked list?

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thank you, but what is the difference between a static linked list and a nested one?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access non-static variables from static, but you can access static from non-static. Your main method is static, that's why you have an error. Read more about the difference between static and non-static.

[I want to know the difference between static method and non-static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903537/i-want-to-know-the-difference-between-static-method-and-non-static-method)

[I want to know the difference between static class and non-static class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)

Answer (score 0):

It works when I revise it a little bit.

```
public static class ListNode<T> {
        public T data;
        public ListNode<T> next;

        ListNode(T data, ListNode<T> next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
```

But why I should add static?

Answer (score 0):

In the example you've provided you are attempting to directly instantiate an inner class.

An inner class is tied to an instance of their outer class (See: [JLS 8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)).  So in short, you cannot have a `Example.ListNode` instance if there is no `Example` instance!

So this leaves you the following options:

1. Move `ListNode` out of `Example` so that it's a top level class.  You will then be able to instantiate `ListNode` in your main method.
2. Mark `ListNode` as `static` which effectively makes it otherwise behave as a top level class.
3. Create an `Example` instance in `main`.  For example `Example example = new Example();`.  Then you should be able to create instances of `ListNode` by calling `new example.ListNode();`.