# Java - Removing an object from an object array

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am writing a large program that involves an Object called `Player`. The Player definition is as follows:

```
public class Player
{
    public static String name;
    public static Item inventory[] = new Item[10];
    public static int items;

    /* ... */

    public void addItem(String itemName, int itemType)
    {
            if ((items + 1) <= 10) {
                    inventory[items] = new Item(itemName, itemType);
                    items++;
            }
    }

    public void removeItem(int x)
    {
            for (int i = x; i < items; i++)
                    inventory[i] = inventory[i+1];
    }
}
```

I am adding inventory handling now because it's much easier than adding it later, but `inventory` isn't going to be used until much later in development. I have no way to see if `removeItem` works. I modified a function I wrote called `strstrip` to get this... Would `removeItem` work? If not, why?

Comment: if you are going to remove stuff, things like Lists would be more suitable. Typically, ArrayList. Nonetheless, no `removeItem` isn't going to work, it crashes, but you would know that if you tested it. Also, you may want to learn what `static` means

Comment: *I have no way to see if removeItem works*: sure you do. Add items, then remove one, then see what inventory contains what it should contain. That said, you're reinventing ArrayList.

Comment: Debug is your friend!

Comment: You may want to look into unit testing. It can help with situations like this.

Comment: Do you know what `static` means? Do you *really* intend to have state shared between all `Player` instances?

Comment: @StephenP and LinkedList needs to traverse all the nodes until the middle one, which is usually slower than shifting a contiguous block of memory. ArrayList is your best bet in nearly all situations.

Comment: Is your inventory specific to each Player object ?

Comment: No. What I disagreed about was: *If you'll be inserting in the middle of the list, LinkedList is a better choice because ArrayList must shift lots of elements to make room for the new one.*

Comment: Arraylists will be going to play vital role here rather than static arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create unit tests for your classes especially if you going to build 'big and complicated program'. This will guarantee you that the code written will work later and if you change your code the failure of unit tests should indicate a problem. The unit test also gives you ability to check that your method works as expected.

As per other comments, consider using List interface instead of array, unless you have some specific requirement (I cannot imagine any). And definitely, having `public static` fields in your class looks suspicious.

**EDIT**

Just to indicate how code can look like and how to call methods from the main method.

```
public class Player {

    private String name;
    private List<Item> inventory;
    private int items;

    public Player() {
        this.inventory = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void addItem(String itemName, int itemType) {
        this.inventory.add(new Item(itemName, itemType));
    }

    public void removeItem(int x) {
        Item itemToRemove = this.inventory.get(x);
        if (itemToRemove != null) {
            this.inventory.remove(itemToRemove);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create a new instance
        Player player = new Player();
        // call a method on the instance
        player.addItem("bla", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I use `static` for everything so that it can be accessed by `public static void main`. Otherwise I get an error - 'cannot access static ... from non-static context'.

Comment: Sure it will complain. The main method is static and in order to use any nonstatic methods from the class you need to create an instance of the class first. If you unsure about static... then check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903537/i-want-to-know-the-difference-between-static-method-and-non-static-method

Comment: what should i do to create an instance of the class - make a `public interface`?

Comment: I modified answer to indicate how to deal with the 'main' method.

Comment: thank you very much, that was extremely helpful! out of curiosity, why should the variables all be private - what would be the benefits? and how would I put the elements in the linked list in a specific order?

Comment: 'private' is for encapsulation and to put value into specific position you can use ' add(int index, E element)' method.