# What is the equivalent of :: operator in java?

Tags: java, function, class, operators

When accessing a function from another class in c++, 
we can write: classA::fct();

Is there an equivalent operator in java? 
If not, how can we access a function from another class in java?

Comment: C++ is not Java.  Don't write Java code using C++ as a model.

Comment: almost completely different  languages, why are you mapping these two languages

Comment: `.`, as in `java.util.Arrays.equals(x, y)`.

Comment: [I want to know the difference between static method and non-static method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3903537/669576)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the `::`-operator ([Scope Resolution Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b451xz31.aspx)) in C++ allows you to resolve ambiguous calls/references to identifiers. However, in java there are no independent functions as all functions are actually methods (members) of a class. As such there are no need for this operator, have a look [here](http://eecs.mines.edu/Courses/csci262-roman/INFO/Classes_in_Java_and_C++.html) for differences between Java and C++ classes.

I am guessing you are attempting to access a member (possibly static) of a class, in which case you'd use the `.`-operator as exemplified in [Mwesigye's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41324224/10251345) or as follows:

```
public class AB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B myB = new B();
        myB.printA();
    }
}

public class A {
    public static int getInt() {
        return 4;
    }
}

public class B {
    public void printA() {
        System.out.println(A.getInt()); // output: 4
    }
}
```

Here the `.`-operator is used to access `printA()` from the instantiated object `myB` (instantiated from class B). It is also used to access the static method `getInt()` whose implementation is tied to class A rather than any object of A. More info can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html).

Answer (score 1):

Take an example of a Class Student with methods what you call  functions in c++
eg.

```
    class Student{ 
    //a non static method
    public void getFees(){
    //your logic
    }  
    public static void deleteSubject(){
    // your logic
    }

} 
class Club{
  //create a new instance of student class
Student student = new Student();
public void printData(){ 
//access a non static method  
student.getFees(); 
//accessing a static method 
new Student().deleteSubject();
}

}
```

Hope this will help.