# Can you use the class for calling method?

Tags: java, class, static

Whenever I have to call a method from another class, I first create an object and then call it through the object. But while I was writing some code, I mistakenly wrote `classname.methodname();` and it worked.

I would usually write,

```
classname obj = new classname();
obj.methodname();
```

Here is the actual code:

Class 1

```
public class Dataset {

    public static List<ECCardData> getDataset() {
         //Code
}
```

in Class 2

```
List<ECCardData> dataset = Dataset.getDataset();
```

I noticed that the `methodname()` was static. Was that the reason?

Comment: I would assume because `methodname` was declared static. It's hard to guess why that is the case without any knowledge of the class structure.

Comment: I assumed the same, Let me update the question with the code I have at hand @Ben

Comment: Also I misread your question, my bad. Yes, that is because it is static. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903537/what-is-the-difference-between-a-static-method-and-a-non-static-method) for more information.

Comment: You may want to go through this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: You should call static methods with the class name. Calling them via an instance e.g. `instance.staticMethod()` is considered bad form because it makes it look like you're calling an instance method.

Comment: Or [What does the 'static' keyword do in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/413898/4391450)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for static methods (with suitable access modifier) you can call directly with your class by

```
YourClass.yourMethod();
```

and this way, too

```
YourClass anObject = new YourClass();
anObject.yourMethod();
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks, could you also share why this works? is it just a static thing

Comment: `static` method is sometime simply a method, but when `ClassLoader` loaded `YourClass` into memory, `yourMethod()` is also loaded. You can use `static` methods by both ways, call by `object` (create `object` and call through it) or call by reference (directly call through owner class).

Comment: using object and calling method doesnt work, I have posted an answer which spread light on the same

Comment: @Vedant you can always call a public static method through public Class's object

Comment: Yes you can call it, but it is highly frowned upon

Comment: You just said it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes I realised and I changed my answer, Thanks john

Answer (score 0):

*I hate answering my question, but I found the correct answer.*

When a method is declare static, only one instance of that method will exist. When you create an object a new instance of the method is created, which is not possible for a static method. Therefore you use the class name.

```
classname.methodname(); //only one instance 

classname obj;
obj.methodname(); //instance with obj as Object(IDE gives warning, should not be allowed, ideally)
```

> The basic paradigm in Java is that you write classes, and that those
>   classes are instantiated. Instantiated objects (an instance of a
>   class) have attributes associated with them (member variables) that
>   affect their behavior; when the instance has its method executed it
>   will refer to these variables.
>
> However, all objects of a particular type might have behavior that is
>   not dependent at all on member variables; these methods are best made
>   static. By being static, no instance of the class is required to run
>   the method.
>
> You can do this to execute a static method:

```
classname.staticMethod();//Simply refers to the class's static code But
> to execute a non-static method, you must do this:
> 
> classname obj = new classname();//Create an instance
> obj.nonstaticMethod();//Refer to the instance's class's code
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with answering your own question on Stack Overflow. But be aware that the second form is considered a bad practice if `methodname()` is a static method, because it makes it look as if it was an instance method.

Comment: Yes, It is not possible to have an instanced static method, let me update the answer

Comment: no instance of method is created,

Comment: no instance of method is created,

Comment: A method has no instance.

Comment: @KhanSaab a static method has one instance, a  non-static method can have multiple instances

Comment: @Vedant A method has no instance, An instance can be created with `new` key word in java. Static method is a property of a class not of an object(instance) of that class.

Comment: You do not correctly use the terms _instance_ and _method_. There simply are no instances of methods. You can have instances of classes, though. Technically, a method's definition existst only once in memory, even if it is an instance method. And speaking about methods, we distinguish between instance methods and static methods (or class methods).