# Declare object into a switch statement

Tags: java

obj not recognized after declaring in switch statement

```
switch (var){
        case "YES" : {
              Object1 obj = new Object1();
              break;
       }
        default: {
              Object2 obj = new Object2();
       }

     }

NewObject newObject = obj.objToNewObject(param);
```

My problem is that "obj" is not recognized
-> "Error java: cannot find symbol"

I was thinking that with "default" i will work but no.
Any help ?

Comment: Declare `Object obj` outside of the switch statement but assign within.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object `obj` in your code is a local variable of the `switch statement`, so it cannot be accessed outside this scope. Also, to be able to use obj as two different classes you will have to use `Polymorphism`, so you will have to declare a base class (I will use A to illustrate) and two different classes (B and C) that extends class A.

```
class A {
    public NewObject(param) {
        return new NewObject();
    }
}
```

```
class B extends A{
    @Override
    public NewObject(param) {
        return new NewObject();
    }
}
```

```
class C extends A { 
    @Override
    public NewObject(param) {
        return new NewObject();
    }
}
```

```
A obj = null;
switch (var){
        case "YES" : {
              obj = new B();
              break;
       }
        case "NO": {
              obj = new C();
       }
        default: {
              obj = new B();
       }

     }
NewObject newObject = obj.objToNewObject(param);
```

Note that the classes B and C will have to `override` the method `objToNewObject` from class A for this to work

Comment: Mh.. its differents object

Comment: @amalicode what is wrong with the answer? It fully answers your question and example is given

Comment: @amalicode Your edit changes nothing.  You still have to declare outside of the switch.

Comment: @amalicode this is the correct answer. What you're trying to do will not work without `Object1` and `Object2 ` sharing a common interface. If they do share a common interface, then `obj` should be declared outside of the switch statement to be an instance of the interface.

Comment: i read it. how chose beetween Object1 and Object2 when i do Object obj = null;

Comment: @amalicode I edited the answer, hope this will help you

Comment: "Method does not override method from its superclass" when i override method @HenriqueSabino

Comment: it was due to "static". But why ?

Comment: @amalicode make sure the methods names are the same as in the base class, also use the annotation `@Override` so then the compiler knows that it should be an overridden method, the syntax should be like I put in the edits

Comment: @amalicode Static methods are class methods while non-static are instance methods, take a look at this link here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903537/what-is-the-difference-between-a-static-method-and-a-non-static-method

Comment: @amalicode Also, read this topic here, this should also help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods