# Java "this" usage

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I am reading a toy code, and notice all the other methods expect "start" and "stop" methods are static. And due to this "stop" can only be called as via ".this.stop()" (The "here" line). What's the advantage implement like this, why not make "start" and "stop" also static methods?

```
public class MyService {
    private MyService() {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MyService.this.stop();                    <----- here
                } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                    ...
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected void stop() {
     ....
    }

    protected void start() {
     ....
    }

    public static xxx getXXX() {
        return xxx;
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: A static method belongs to a class, rather than an instance of it. It seems that the purpose of the start and stop methods are to start or stop an instance of a class  and not the class itself. A static method can be called by the class as a whole (e.g MyClass.staticMethod())  and you don't need an object to call it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a static method and a non-static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903537/what-is-the-difference-between-a-static-method-and-a-non-static-method)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the `stop()` call is inside an anonymous class extending `Thread` so it has its own `stop()` method inherited from `Thread`:

```java
   new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                MyService.this.stop();                    <----- here
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

The whole statement is `MyService.this.stop();`, it is not just `this.stop()` which would be no difference to `stop()` alone in this case. This notation - `MyService.this` - is used inside enclosed (nested) classes to denote the enclosing instance, the instance of `MyService` in this case. See Java Language Specification [15.8.4. Qualified this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4).

This notation is only needed if the enclosed class has a member with the same name/signature as the enclosing class. In this case, if the method had a different name, `stopService` for example, there would be no need for a qualified or simple `this` at all.

---

Note: since it is not intended to change the functionality of the `Thread` class, I recommend not to extend it, but instead to use a `Runnable` passed as argument in its constructor:

```java
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // the code
        }
    });
```

This would avoid having to use the qualified `this` (it still can be used).
It would also avoid any unwanted access to the `Thread` members.

Answer (score 0):

`this` means **this instance** (in the scope). So, if the `stop` or the `start` method is meant to stop or to start a MyService instance, it should be non-static.