# Call function of unnamed object in using statement

Tags: c#, .net, using-statement

Trying to learn `using` statement. How to call `add` function of newly created unnamed object in `tst()` function:

```
public class AnswerCmd : IDisposable
{

    public static void tst()
    {
        using (new AnswerCmd())
        {
            //add(5); not works
        }

    }



    public void add(int value)
    {
        //....
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `add` is not [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static), you need to create a new instance of `AnswerCmd` to access it, like this:

```
using (var instance = new AnswerCmd())
{
    instance.add(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because  `tst` function is a static function, but `add` functuon isn't.

If you want to create an instance try to remove `static`

```
public class AnswerCmd : IDisposable
{

    public void add(int value)
    {

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

}
```

then you can use like this in outside

```
using (var ans = new AnswerCmd())
{
    ans.add(5);
}
```

**Note**

remove `throw new NotImplementedException();` in `Dispose` function otherwise, you will get the error when your leave the `using`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost Ok but if you change your code a little more you can do what you want. This is your code with a little change:

```
public class AnswerCmd : IDisposable
{
    public static void tst()
    {
        using (AnswerCmd var = new AnswerCmd())
        {
            var.add(5);
        }
    }

    public void add(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Add: {value}");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You must declare a variable `AnswerCmd var` in your using statement in type of your class and then after creating and assigning and object to it like this `AnswerCmd var = new AnswerCmd()` call your `add` method like this `var.add()`.

If you want to know more about that and why you should do that, I have to say this is because your `tst` method is **static** and your `add` method is **non-static**. non-static methods are just for objects of your class and you cannot call them when you don’t created an object from that class.  When you call a non-static method directly without creating an object this is a syntactic error.

You also must remove or comment `throw new NotImplementedException();` in `Dispose` method because, your method will throw and `Exception` when you leave the using.

This is good if you visit [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155474/difference-between-static-and-non-static-members) and read more about differences between static and non-static methods.