# C# ASP.NET How to use the method of a Class in the Helpers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

so... it's a pretty dumb question but i was searching and didn't found a didatic answer...

I created this Class on my Helpers folder, to use it on the controller, to make some clean code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CarroBemGuardado.Helpers
{
    public class CalcularValorPagar
    {
        static decimal CalcularPagamento (string dur, decimal ph, decimal hadd)
        {
            decimal valorpagar = 0;
            decimal horas = Convert.ToDecimal(dur.Substring(0, 2));
            decimal minutos = Convert.ToDecimal(dur.Substring(3, 2));

            if ((horas == 0) && (minutos <= 30))
            {
                valorpagar = ph / 2;
            }
            else if ((horas > 0) && (minutos > 10))
            {
                valorpagar = ph + (hadd * horas);
            }
            else if ((horas > 0) && (minutos < 10))
            {
                valorpagar = ph + (hadd * (horas - 1));
            }
            else
            {
                valorpagar = ph;
            }

            return valorpagar;
        }
    }
}
```

But i'm trying to call the method CalcularPagamento on my controller (and pass the 3 parameters to it) but i can't. I can only call the Class. I tried to instantiate the Class to call the method but also didn't worked.

How can i do that ?

Comment: you should mark the method as public! :)

Comment: @ashin means your code should look like `public static decimal Calcular....`

Comment: And then call `CalcularValorPagar.CalcularPagamento(...)`

Comment: yes, try that and then access it as CalcularValorPagar.CalcularPagamento()

Comment: i did this, gonna test it to see it works.

CalcularValorPagar valor = new CalcularValorPagar();

                decimal retorno = valor.CalcularPagamento(duracao, consultapreco.preco_hora, consultapreco.hora_adicional);

Comment: You can't call `static methods` with `instance of class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide `public` [Access-Modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers) for your `static` method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CarroBemGuardado.Helpers
{
    public class CalcularValorPagar
    {
        public static decimal CalcularPagamento (string dur, decimal ph, decimal hadd)
        {
            decimal valorpagar = 0;
            decimal horas = Convert.ToDecimal(dur.Substring(0, 2));
            decimal minutos = Convert.ToDecimal(dur.Substring(3, 2));

            if ((horas == 0) && (minutos <= 30))
            {
                valorpagar = ph / 2;
            }
            else if ((horas > 0) && (minutos > 10))
            {
                valorpagar = ph + (hadd * horas);
            }
            else if ((horas > 0) && (minutos < 10))
            {
                valorpagar = ph + (hadd * (horas - 1));
            }
            else
            {
                valorpagar = ph;
            }

            return valorpagar;
        }
    }
}
```

And in your `Controller`, you could access it as follow:

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    string sDur = "someValue";
    decimal dPH = 2;
    decimal dHadd = 3;
    decimal valorpagar = CalcularValorPagar.CalcularPagamento(sDur, dPH, dHadd );

   return View();
}
```

---

You don't need to instantiate your helper class `CalcularValorPagar` to access your any `static methods` within  `CalcularValorPagar` class.

This is the real beauty (*i like the most*) of `static methods` that you could call them without creating `instance` of `class` in which these `static methods` reside.

Related SO Threads([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124102/whats-a-static-method-in-c) & [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184701/static-vs-non-static-method) ) for Static methods.

Comment: It's not necessary to initialize the class with CalcularValorPagar abc = new CalcularValorPagar(); ?

Comment: yes it is not necessary to instantiate your class. Please have a look at [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124102/whats-a-static-method-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

your code should be changed like this so you can access the helper method from other class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CarroBemGuardado.Helpers
{
    public class CalcularValorPagar
    {
       public static decimal CalcularPagamento (string dur, decimal ph, decimal hadd)
        {
            decimal valorpagar = 0;
            decimal horas = Convert.ToDecimal(dur.Substring(0, 2));
            decimal minutos = Convert.ToDecimal(dur.Substring(3, 2));

            if ((horas == 0) && (minutos <= 30))
            {
                valorpagar = ph / 2;
            }
            else if ((horas > 0) && (minutos > 10))
            {
                valorpagar = ph + (hadd * horas);
            }
            else if ((horas > 0) && (minutos < 10))
            {
                valorpagar = ph + (hadd * (horas - 1));
            }
            else
            {
                valorpagar = ph;
            }

            return valorpagar;
        }
    }
}
```